# Intel Media SDK streaming output

Tags: streaming, intel, video-encoding, intel-media-sdk

So i'm trying to use Intel Media SDK to Encode camera frames using Intel Quick Sync technology, so far i have managed to encode raw frames coming in from the camera from OpenCV into final output of raw mfxBitStream

Now my question is, i would like to stream the encoded output to lets say, VLC or anything else
how can i do that?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Hi, How did you capture the frames into media sdk ? Is there any sample showing it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can save your output in a file, a then add it to VLC. I did it sometime ago and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command: (where video.yuv - the output of sample_decode application):

vlc --demux rawvideo --rawvid-fps 25 --rawvid-width 1920 --rawvid-height 1088 --rawvid-chroma I420 video.yuv